# How many IP addresses can I expect to block on a Cisco 5500-X Series firewall?

Tags: firewall, cisco, ip, cisco-asa

Considering a Cisco ASA (5500-X) firewall for our internet edge in front of our web cluster.

At the moment, we use a Linux box with iptables. A log analysis system detects brute-force attacks on WordPress blogs, forum spam, hacking attempts, and much more. Illicit activity will result in a short-lived block of the offending IP address.

The list of blocked IPs, however, is around 30,000 IPv4 addresses. Can we load these into a Cisco 5500-X using an API or similar, and how many IP addresses / rules can it handle?

We currently use ipset (a hashtable) to deal with the large number of IP blocks.

Thanks!

Comment: How much RAM does the ASA have?  (I can't answer the question, but my experience does indicate that the amount of RAM in the ASA will have a significant impact on the answer.)

Comment: We are looking at one with 8 GB of memory, but I think some have 16 GB.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a thread from the ASA Business Unit.  This is for an ASA 5520 (only 512 MB of RAM) and it serviced 300k ACE (access control expressions; e.g. lines in an ACL)

https://supportforums.cisco.com/thread/2064748

In short even an older non-X-series ASA like the 5520 could handle 300,000 one line denies - so handling 10% of that should be a non-issue.